# java method in seperate class file giving no symbol error

Tags: java

I have set up a class in a second file which is in the same package as the main but for some reason I am unable to call it without it giving a "`cannot find symbol error`" even though I'm sure everything is ok. This is a basic file I tried and it replicated exactly the same but im not sure if its my code or netbeans.

```
package filesystem;

public class FileSystem {


public static void main(String[] args) {
 FileMethods(Hello);  
   }
}
```

and the other class

```
package filesystem;

public class FileMethods {


public void FileMethods(String myString){
    System.out.println(myString);
    } 
}
```

This is the error i get next to the line

![image: Error]

thanks for any help

Comment: You haven't declared variable `Hello`.

Comment: You probably want to use a String literal, i.e. "Hello" instead of Hello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
new FileMethods("Hello");
```

You cannot call a constructor directly without creating a new object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted to do

```
new FileMethods("Hello");
```

To print the string Hello.

Here you are trying to reference the variable Hello which doesn't exists.